# QGIS or PostGIS auto-split long line features

Tags: qgis, python, postgis

I have a dataset of LineStrings in a postgis enabled database and would like to automatically split any feature longer than a certain threshold (say 1 mile).  I am aware of the Split Feature tool in QGIS but since my dataset contains potentially millions of lines, I need an automatic solution.

Is there a pre-existing function or something that can help me with this?  I could write a Python script to go through each feature, and if its length > threshold then split at location X.  But I am not sure how to actually split the line and maintain all other attributes

I can use ArcGIS if necessary but would strongly prefer to use open source tools

Comment: I think that ST_Segmentize() (http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Segmentize.html) will do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of `generate_series` and window `LEAD` function to generate `dist_from` and `dist_to` fields and use `ST_LineSubstring` to cut lines at some interval (here: 1000 m).

```sql
SELECT
  row_number() OVER() new_id,
  b.id,
  ST_LineSubstring(lin.the_geom, b.dist_from/ST_Length(lin.the_geom), LEAST(b.dist_to/ST_Length(lin.the_geom), 1)) geom
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id,
    dist dist_from,
    LEAD(dist) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dist) dist_to
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      generate_series(0, ceil(ST_Length(lin.the_geom)/1000.0)::int*1000, 1000) dist
    FROM
      lin
  ) a
) b
JOIN
  lin ON b.id = lin.id
WHERE
  b.dist_to IS NOT NULL
```